# Skip blanks cells in a dynamic AdvancedFilter CriteriaRange

Tags: excel, vba

How do I skip/ignore blank cells in my CriteriaRange (AdvancedFilter)?

```vb
Sub BrandExtraction ()

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Dim rngCrit As Range
Dim rngData As Range

Set rngData = Sheets("ProductPriceExport").Range("A1").CurrentRegion

With Sheets("Campaign")
    Set rngCrit = .Range("C1", .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

rngData.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=rngCrit, CopyToRange:=Range("A1:AN1"), Unique:=False
```

---

I found an option to sort the Campaign sheet (Colum B) if it is a table area.

I tried the ActiveSheet.ListObjects function ("Table1"). ListColumns (2) .DataBodyRange.Select, but it's still copying the whole dataset from ProductPriceExport file.

```vb
Sub PrimaryBrandExtractionTestTable()

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Dim rngCrit As Range
Dim rngData As Range
Dim tbl As ListObject

**Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("KampagneTabel")**
Set rngData = Sheets("ProductPriceExport").Range("A1").CurrentRegion

With Sheets("Campaign")
    Set rngCrit = **tbl.ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange.Select**   
End With

rngData.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CriteriaRange:=rngCrit, CopyToRange:=Sheets("BrandExtraction").Range("A1:AN1"), Unique:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the name of the worksheet containing this range `Range("A1:AN1")`? What exactly is in the cells of the range `C1:CLastRow`?

Comment: The worksheet containing the Range("A1:AN1") is named "BrandExtraction"

 - Another thing that annoys me is that can only execute the macro when I stand in that sheet.


The cells of the range C1:CLastRow is 'brand names', and therefore text strings. Hope it's helps! :)

Comment: How did you come up with the columns `A:AN`? Are these the same as in the `ProductPriceExport` worksheet? To not be forced to run from the critical worksheet, you have to qualify its range with `Worksheets("BrandExtraction").Range("A1:AN1")`.

Comment: You could avoid the empty cells in `C1:CLastRow` by sorting the column which you probably don't wanna do. I'm opting for deleting the empty rows from the `BrandExtraction` worksheet but I need you to clarify what I last asked and I need you to tell me in which column of the `ProductPriceExport` worksheet the `Brand Names` are.

Comment: Yes it's the same colums as ProductPriceExport. The colum with Brand Names are colum I.

I don't understand what you mean by deleting the empty rows from the BrandExtraction - after the copy is excuted? When i have blank cells in range C1:CLastRow it gonna copy all my data in ProduktPriceExport.. That's the issue. And thanks again! :)

Comment: @VBasic2008 I have updated the body with new information..

Answer (score 1):

### Using Advanced Filter (With a Little Help From `AutoFilter`)

- You should probably do the whole thing by using `AutoFilter`.
- The second solution uses `AutoFilter` to remove the copied 'blanks'.

```vb
Option Explicit


Sub BrandExtractionBasic()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code

    Dim rngData As Range
    Set rngData = wb.Worksheets("ProductPriceExport").Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    Dim rngCrit As Range
    With wb.Worksheets("Campaign")
        Set rngCrit = .Range("C1", .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With
    
    Dim rngCopy As Range
    With wb.Worksheets("BrandExtraction")
        .UsedRange.Clear
        Set rngCopy = .Range("A1").Resize(, rngData.Columns.Count)
    End With
    
    rngData.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, rngCrit, rngCopy
     
End Sub


Sub BrandExtraction()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code

    Dim rngData As Range
    Set rngData = wb.Worksheets("ProductPriceExport").Range("A1").CurrentRegion

    Dim rngCrit As Range
    With wb.Worksheets("Campaign")
        Set rngCrit = .Range("C1", .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    End With

    With wb.Worksheets("BrandExtraction")
        .UsedRange.Clear
        Dim rngCopy As Range
        Set rngCopy = .Range("A1").Resize(, rngData.Columns.Count)

    
        rngData.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, rngCrit, rngCopy
        
        Set rngCopy = .Range("A1").CurrentRegion ' reusing variable!
        With rngCopy
            Set rngData = .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1) ' reusing variable!
            .AutoFilter 9, "=" ' filter blanks ('9' means 'I' column)
        End With
        
        Dim rngVisible As Range
        On Error Resume Next
            Set rngVisible = rngData.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        
        If Not rngVisible Is Nothing Then rngVisible.Delete xlShiftUp
    
    End With
     
End Sub
```

Comment: Both sulotions is coping the whole ProductPriceExport sheet - testet with and without blank cells. Is there other information that would help?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
CriteriaRange:=Array(rngCrit, "<>")
```

I have not tested it

Comment: Thanks for input.. It comes with a error when trying your suggestion. "Run time error '13': Type mismatch,